# ASP.NET Core WebAPI 404 error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I create a Web Api in asp.net core this the content of Api:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BlogController : Controller
{

    public IContext _context { get; set; }
    public BlogController(IContext ctx)
    {
        _context = ctx;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Blog/GetAllBlog")]
    public List<Blog> GetAllBlog()
    {
        return _context.Blogs.ToList();
    }


   }
```

as i know in ASp.net Core (WebApi Template) we don't need any configuration like registration Route, which we need in Asp.net Mvc 5.3 and older.

So when i try to call the `GetAllBlog` by browser or Postman, by this url `http://localhost:14742/api/Blog/GetAllBlog` , it gets me `404 error`, what is problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have already included the api/[controller] route at the top of the controller class so you don't need to include it again while defining route for accessing method.
In essence, change the Route to api/Blog/GetAllBlog to GetAllBlog. Your code should look like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BlogController : Controller
{

    public IContext _context { get; set; }
    public BlogController(IContext ctx)
    {
        _context = ctx;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetAllBlog")]
    public List<Blog> GetAllBlog()
    {
        return _context.Blogs.ToList();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetOldBlogs")]
    public List<Blog> GetOldBlogs()
    {
        return _context.Blogs.Where(x => x.CreationDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2)).ToList();
    }
}
```

You also need to have different route names for methods.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Is int not possible to just have the route be named implicitly without having to use the [Route] attribute?