# How to invoke a controller method using react-query?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using react-query for data operations and using asp.net Core Web Api for backend. I tried to fetch data by invoking a controller method but, it returned '**Status with 404 not found**' error. I tried different ways but nothing seems to work.
What's I'm doing wrong here ?

App.js

```
const queryProvider = new QueryClient();

function App(){
  return(
     <QueryClientProvider client={queryProvider}>
        <Test />
        <ReactQueryDevtools/>
     </QueryClientProvider>
   );
}

function Test() {
    const { isLoading, error, data, isFetching } = useQuery("fetchKey", () =>
        axios.get(
            "https://localhost:7036/api/general/getmaturedata"
        ).then((res) => res.data)
    );

    if (isLoading) return "Loading...";

    if (error) return "An error has occurred: " + error.message;
}
```

Controller.cs

```
[ApiController]
public class GeneralController : ControllerBase
{
        [Route("api/general/getmaturedata")]
        [HttpPost]

        public IActionResult GetMatureData()
        {
            return new JsonResult(true);
        }
}
```

launchSettings.json

```
"profiles": {
     "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7036;http://localhost:5036",
     "dotnetRunMessages": true
}
```

**Note**: I'm trying to hit a Debugger point in the controller method in order to test whether the code works or not. There are no data is provided yet.

Comment: If you open the URL you are trying to get in a new tab, does it also give you a 404?

Comment: @JakubKotrs Yes it does

Comment: In that case, it's not a problem on the frontend with React and/or React Query. You could simplify the question to ASP.net only. (Sorry, I came here for the frontend tags.)

Comment: @JakubKotrs Thanks for pointing that out ... I will simplify the question

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

As @JakubKotrs mentioned it was not on react-query but, web API itself. I changed the controller and router respectively and solved the problem

similar answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422325/asp-net-core-webapi-404-error)